# Consider extension $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\ ):\mathbb{Q}]$ where $\alpha\ $ is zero of $P(x) = x^4 + 9x^{2} + 15 $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Consider extension $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$ where $\alpha$ is zero of  $p(x) = x^4 + 9x^{2} + 15 $. Find $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2 + 3)]$.

My attempt: By Eisenstein's Criterion $p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ and by Gauss's lemma it is also over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}] = 4$. Now as $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2 + 3)] [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2 + 3):\mathbb{Q}]$ we have 
$$
4 = [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2 + 3)] [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2 + 3):\mathbb{Q}] \, .
$$
There are three possibilities: $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2 + 3)] = 1,2$ or $4$.

As $\alpha$ is zero of $p(x) = x^4 + 9x^{2} + 15$, I can write $p(x) = (x - \alpha)(x + \alpha)(x^2 + 9 + \alpha^2)$ on $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. I got stuck here.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: One way to proceed is to simply compute the roots of $x^4 + 9x^2 +15$ using the quadratic formula, and then compute $\alpha^2 + 3$ explicitly.

Comment: It is possible, but  we do not know what is $ \alpha\ $.

Comment: @JuniorSoares As you commented in my now deleted answer, you **do know**  what $\;\alpha\;$ is (the four roots, in fact) ...

Comment: Yes, but we have to ensure that $\alpha^2 + 3\ $ is not in $\mathbb{Q(\alpha\ )}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pretty much got an answer :)! However, I think it would be a little bit easier to calculate the degree extension of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2+3)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. We can proceed as following:

First of all note that $\alpha^2+3$ is not a rational number (why?), so $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2+3):\mathbb{Q}]$ can't be 1. It remains for us find out what is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^2+3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. To find such polynomial, the natural thing to do is to set $$x=\alpha^2+3 \space$$ Or equivalently, $x-3=\alpha^2$ (*). Squaring both side of this equation, taking advantage of the fact that $\alpha$ is a zero of $x^4+9x^2+15$ to manipulate algebraically into $x^2+3x-3=0$. So consider $m(x)=x^2+3x-3$.

Now can you check that $m$ is indeed the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^2+3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? This is a routine exercise. Once you have that, think of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2+3)$ as $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(m(x))$. So it must be the case that $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2+3):\mathbb{Q}]=2$

Comment: Very good answer! I can understand all steps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using Eisenstein criterion to $x^4+9x^2+15=0$ with $p=3$, we have that the minimal polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. So $\alpha\notin\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2+3)$, for otherwise the minimal polynomial would be of degree 2. Note that the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2+3)$ is $x^2-\alpha^2$. So $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2+3)]=2$.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment: Since $\alpha$ is a root of $x^4+9x^2 +15$, then $\alpha^2$ is a root of $x^2 + 9x + 15$.  Then
$$
\alpha^2 = \frac{-9 \pm \sqrt{21}}{2}
$$
by the quadratic formula.  Let $\beta = \alpha^2 + 3$.  Then
\begin{align*}
\beta - 3 = \alpha^2 = \frac{-9 \pm \sqrt{21}}{2} &\implies 2\beta + 3 = \pm \sqrt{21} \implies 21 = (2\beta+3)^2 = 4\beta^2 + 12\beta +9\\
&\implies 0 = 4\beta^2 + 12\beta - 12 = 4(\beta^2 + 3\beta - 3) \, .
\end{align*}
Then $\beta$ satisfies $x^2 + 3x - 3$, which is irreducible by Eisenstein.  Thus $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta) : \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2 + 3) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

9($\alpha^2$ + 3)= 12 -$\alpha^4$ imply $\alpha^4$ + 9a - 12 = 0 and this polynomial is irreducible (Eisenstein) hence the asked
 degree is 4.

Remark: Maybe I'm wrong and my polynomial is reducible (because of $\alpha^2$ + 3)....

Comment: If $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\ ):\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2 + 3)]$ were of degree 4,  $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha^2 + 3\ ):\mathbb{Q}]$ would have degree 1, and $\alpha^2 + 3\ $ would be rational, what not is possible.

Comment: @JuniorSoares: Yes, this was my doubt (believed me, please, I have edit before read your comment)

Comment: I believe. Before @Timbuc has pointed out the fact that this degree can not be four. Anyway, i appreciate your help.